# Using Mongoose middleware find query document from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using mongoose middleware connect to mongodb.

I have MongoDB collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54801a4def32fe8c2bc642a6"), "name" : "Cyber KOK", "serial" : null } 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54801a4def32fe8c2bc642a5"), "name" : "Cyber KOK", "serial" : "" } 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54801a4def32fe8c2bc642a7"), "name" : "Cyber KOK", "serial" : " " } 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54801a4def32fe8c2bc642a8"), "name" : "Cyber KOK", "serial" : "14A16" } 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54801a4def32fe8c2bc642a9"), "name" : "Cyber KOK", "serial" : "19B20" }
```

How do you query mongodb collection using mongoose to display as below in one command?

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54801a4def32fe8c2bc642a6"), "name" : "Cyber KOK", "serial" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54801a4def32fe8c2bc642a5"), "name" : "Cyber KOK", "serial" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54801a4def32fe8c2bc642a7"), "name" : "Cyber KOK", "serial" : " " }
```

Thank you.
WJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
Model.find({$or : [{serial: ""}, {serial: " "}, {serial: null}]}, function(){...});
```